# Create column and set value where multiple other column conditions are met

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

New to using pandas and need to convert some SAS code.  Trying to create a column and set a value if multiple other column conditions are met.

Here's what I tried, however it only ever populates the column with all 0's.

```
df['newcol'] = np.where((df['col2']!='') & (df['col3']=='') & (df['col4']==''), 1, 0)
```

yields all 1's even though col2 and col3 do not contain blank values.

Essentially I want a 1 in the column when the conditions are met, I don't need a 0 to be populated when they are NOT met(I found that example on some other SO posts).  My guess is that my data, being characters, is causing the problem.

Comment: Can not reproduced , and not sample data

Comment: What you think is a blank is probably whitespaces.

Comment: Try to isolate your problem. Just use on filter first, and see if that works, then add another, and see if you can find where the problem is.

Comment: without sample data, it's hard to help

Comment: Going to post  some sample data since it's a bit of an odd situation